# Python capturing groups with regex and conditional inserts

Tags: regex, option-type, backreference, capturing-group

I have the below which finds the given pattern and returns it without the space in the middle. This works, but I also want to add a `/` between `\g<2>` and `\g<3>` in the sub, but only when it is not already there; otherwise there will be a duplicate `//`. Everything I've tried messes up the capturing groups. Any help?

```
pattern = re.compile(r"((\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}) (/?(\d{4}|\d{2})))")

report_text = pattern.sub("\g<2>\g<3>", report_text)
```

Here are my inputs and expected result:

```
Inputs                    Expected

02/58 98                  02/58/98
02/58 /98                 02/58/98
02/58 9518                02/58/9518
02/58 /98                 02/58/9518
```

Comment: Can't you just match ` \/?` and replace with `/`? https://regex101.com/r/7Hoqnu/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern seems to overuse capturing groups a bit. You can place the optional `/?` outside of capturing groups, so it will be matched but not reinserted and simply use `/` in the replace, like

```
re.sub(r'(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}) /?(?:(\d{4}|\d{2}))', r'\g<1>/\g<2>', report_text)
```

See also https://ideone.com/YuWrAy

Comment: You are absolutely right. Thanks. I was tunnel visioned.